# What is the piano song that Allie French plays in "Appaloosa"?

Tags: soundtrack, appaloosa-2008

Could anyone please spot the piano song that Renée Zellweger (as Allie French) plays around 23–24 minutes into the movie *Appaloosa* (2008), just before she starts playing "Camptown Races"?

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE! I'm afraid that soundtrack identification questions are off-topic here.

Comment: Is [this the song](https://youtu.be/05qQRyxL8Nk?si=b-8GHyNY4k95xSLO) you're looking for? Shazam it like I did...

Comment: OldPadawan, The one you found is towards the end of the movie. 
The one I had requested for is around 23-24 min from the start. Shazam couldn't catch it because of the dialogues.

Comment: Voting to leave this question open. As far as I know, while questions that ask to identify movies and TV shows (and episodes) are off-topic here, there is [*neither* a site policy nor a community consensus to ban *all* questions that involve identifying something about a movie](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4897/1006) (link leads to relevant [meta] post).

Comment: @galacticninja And that is even without going into the "trivial" aspect of it, for which reason most people apparently were against it, and which has been reconsidered recently. VTLO.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: for some reason I totally missed that the question had camptown races in it (I don't recall seeing it there when I first read the question).

So this is no longer an answer, just a lead for someone else to try to find an answer:

I AI'd the dialogue out to get the [piano playing part](https://jmp.sh/s/pjlbChTb0zICptb3ruyp) before Camptown Races:

I submitted it to the usual desktop ones, phone not handy atm, with no hits.

Comment: I think the main theme is restated just before the end. The material at the beginning of the clip is from a bridge of sorts and would be less recognizable. I recognize the theme but can’t name it.

Comment: trimmed: https://jmp.sh/8tGFcs9U