What song does Angélique sing near Émilie Dubreuil's deathbed?
In the French TV series Les Petits Meurtres d'Agatha Christie, Season 1, Episode 3 "La Plume Empoisonnée" (based on Agatha Christie's novel The Moving Finger), the character Émilie Dubreuil, played by Françoise Bertin, is poisoned.
When she lies on her deathbed, her employee Angélique (played by Corinne Masiero), though a rather cantankerous woman, is deeply moved, since she has a real fondness for her employer. She sings a very beautiful, nostalgic song. It lasts just a few seconds, around 40 to 45 minutes after the beginning. But it has been haunting me since I saw that episode.
Can anyone recognise this song? Thanks! (Uploaded sample)
I don't think it is a French song. For some reason, I think it evokes Spanish lyrics to me. The first line, before it starts to repeat, I feel it ends with:

... la noche.

i.e., "the night" in Spanish. The group "ch" sounded just like in English, "tch" in French, "tsch" in German.
But of course, it is just a very fleeting memory. It might well be completely wrong.

None of the videos seem available, so that would be easier with a timeline (for the DVD) or a sound maybe?

Alfred: please be Leonard and not shiny Sheldon :D :D :D

@OldPadawan Alas, I have only kept a very short part of the recorded TV episode. But comparing at which time it starts (as indicated on my recorder) and the time the episodes typically start, I'd judge that it begins shortly after 40 minutes after the beginning and less than 45. Sorry I don't get the joke here. I understand you refer to BBT, but how can I improve my question to be Leonard instead of Sheldon ?

I have the sound on my video recorder, but I have no idea how to make it available on this forum.

Maybe you can put it online and share the link ? Dunno if it's accepted here though.  TBBT was just a joke because y'all are theoretical physicists and Leonard is such a good mate while Sheldon is... well, Sheldon :)

Soundcloud let you upload your sound for free and share the link, might be helpful

First I should get the sound on my computer. But I don't know how to do it. I know how to read a video or a soundtrack from a from USB-key but not how to write from my recorder to a USB-key.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Paulie_D I can’t find anything in the meta suggesting song ID is not off topic. Most recent conversation was about whether it should be explicitly spelled out in the help that it is off topic. The result of that q&a was not that it’s on topic. The result was since all ID is off topic there’s no need to make it more complicated by specifically mentioning music. What is on topic is “why was this song used?” But “what song was used?” Is off topic.

@ToddWilcox Apparently you are correct ☺ Mostly, ID-movie/actor/song are OT but apparently Id-Prop isn't (used to be trivia but that went away).

@ToddWilcox Well, most "what is this song.." questions are very old. But this one https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/122223/what-is-the-piano-song-that-allie-french-plays-in-appaloosa?rq=1  is recent and though there is indeed a discussion about it being off-topic, it was not closed

@ToddWilcox Can you link to that topic? Also, topics don't require a meta thread to explicate they're not off-topic. A comment on the question linked by Alfred links to a meta discussion where the only existing answer points out "only questions that ask to identify movies and TV shows (and episodes) are considered off-topic". Banning ID questions was already badly received by the community, so I don't get why this is still being pushed against so hard (that's a more general remark, not pointed at you :).

@Joachim I just went down a rabbit hole and got pretty confused. There are links to what I was able to find in my new meta question about this situation: https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5030/im-confused-about-id-questions-where-is-the-successful-vote-to-ban-them

Alfred : upload and share. And, on a computer, more help. Hope this helps

@galacticninja - thanks, edited it in to the Q

My first thought was that it might be an old french nursery rhyme, but i have not found it. Aha and shazam didn't work either

It doesn't sound like a french tune to my ear. Rather spanish. For some reason I "hear" lyrics that sound spanish (but I do not speak spanish !)

Voting to leave this question open. There is neither a site policy nor a community consensus to ban all questions that involve identifying something about a movie. In fact, the community has not shown support for banning identification questions altogether.

The song being hummed in the question is an Italian children's song, Ninna nanna a sette e venti. (If the YouTube link doesn't work for you, just google the title.)



The lyrics (which vary a little depending on the source):

Ninna nanna a sette e venti,
il bambino s'addormenti.
s'addormenta e fa un bel sonno
e si sveglia domani a giorno.
Nanna ieri, nanna ieri
e le sporte non son panieri
e i panieri non son le sporte
e la vita non è la morte
e la morte non è la vita
La canzone l'è già finita.

Basically a lullaby, it mentions falling asleep, the final lines (bolded) translating to,

and life is not death
and death is not life.

That the melody is haunting is an understatement. I've only heard it once before, in the 1986 movie, The Name of the Rose, in which the character Salvatori sings it as he is being put to death by burning at the stake. Since I didn't know Italian or Latin at the time, I didn't understand the words, but have hummed it countless times since then. So, thanks for the mystery solved.

Good catch! I have watched the "name of the rose" countless times, but didn't recognise the songs and match them, will have to watch it again :) you positive about that?

@OldPadawan - Yes, absolutely. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLz9qzvjAB0

Wow, good answer! I stopped looking! Never thought it might be Italian!

@blobbymcblobby - Romance languages are much more alike than they are different. If you guessed any romance language, you weren't far off. I'm just thrilled to know the lyrics after all these years!

The Name of the Rose Yes! This is where I heard it first, and why I got this vague memory of the lyrics. Italian, not Spanish. But as romance language go, these two are closer (in sound at least) to each other than they are to French.

@Alfred - So glad you asked the question! I only heard it that once 38 years or so ago, and have been humming it for that long. I was, maybe not haunted, but certainly enchanted.
